# Django Routing w/ subApplication

Tags: python, django, routes, url-routing, django-urls

What I have:

- a `Django Project` that is acting as a REST API through Django Rest Framework.
- a number of `Django Apps` that are controlling the logic of my Postgres DB.

What I am trying to do:

- Create a new `Django App` that represents a `Service / Integration` with Robinhood
- Within ^^ I want to structure my logic in `subApplications` in order to separate all logic for a `user` vs a `transactions` vs a `transfers` etc ...
- This entire `Django App` & all `subApplications` are APIs ONLY ... they will never need `models / migrations` but they will eventually communicate with the other `Django Apps`

---

CODE STRUCTURE:

- Main `Django Project`

```
├── APP_holdings
├── APP_logs
├── APP_unique
├── APP_users
├── ⭐️⭐️ DJANGO
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── fixtures
│   │   ├── platforms.json
│   │   └── symbols.json
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── EXAMPLE.env
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── ⭐️⭐️ SERVICE_robinhood
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── ⭐️⭐️ user
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── api
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── login.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── utils.py
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── printSomething.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   └── __init__.py
└── staticfiles
```

SETTINGS.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Pre Installed
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Apps
    'APP_users.apps.AppUserConfig',
    'APP_holdings.apps.AppHoldingsConfig',
    'APP_logs.apps.AppLogsConfig',
    'APP_unique.apps.AppUniqueConfig',

    # !!! --- I AM ASSUMING I AM IMPORTING THE APP INCORRECTLY (and have tried many different ways mentioned on various SO threads -> See `.apps` code --- !!!
    'SERVICE_robinhood.apps.ServiceRobinhoodConfig',
    'SERVICE_robinhood.user.apps.UserConfig',

    # Helpers
    'corsheaders',

    # Django Rest Framework
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]
```

SERVICE_robinhood/apps.py

```
class ServiceRobinhoodConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'SERVICE_robinhood'
```

SERVICE_robinhood/user/apps.py

```
class UserConfig(AppConfig):
    # name = 'user'
    name = 'SERVICE_robinhood.user'
```

DJANGO.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # ...auth...

    path('user/', include('APP_users.urls')),
    # ...otherApps...

    path('RH/', include('SERVICE_robinhood.urls'))
]
```

SERVICE_robinhood/urls.py

```
# ?? do I need to import user here and pass it differently into `include` ??
# I thought that since `users` should be a module in and of itself in the overall Django Project you could just reference the app by name

urlpatterns = [
    ❌ path('user/', include('user.urls')),
    ✅ UPDATE - FROM ANSWER: ✅ path('user/', include('SERVICE_robinhood.user.urls')),
]
```

SERVICE_robinhood/user/urls.py

```
from . import utils
urlpatterns = [
    path('printSomething/', utils.printSomething, name='printSomething')
]
```

---

**Error I am getting:**

```
SERVICE_robinhood/urls.py", line 23
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'user'
```

I am assuming that this is an issue with how I am importing the sub application into the overall app but have added all the relevant code I can think of to uncover any other problems.

Comment: Try referencing the full path to the app : `path('user/', include('SERVICE_robinhood.user.urls')),`

Comment: This solved it! Thanks you @AmineMessaoudi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Amine's answer ([ProfileLink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593642/amine-messaoudi)) do the following in your `Django App` to import a `subApplications` routes:

SERVICE_robinhood.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('user/', include('SERVICE_robinhood.user.urls')),
]
```